# Euler transform binomial zeta sum

Tags: calculus

Could you Show?
$$\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \zeta ((n-k)+2)}{(n-k)+2}\approx \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}-\frac{(-1)^n}{2 (n+1) (n+2)}$$ it useful to sum
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \zeta (k+2)}{k+2}=\gamma$$

Comment: If *k* goes from $0$ to *n*, then $n-k$ goes from *n* to $0$. This, in conjunction with $\displaystyle{n\choose k}={n\choose n-k}$ and $\zeta(x)\simeq1$ for $x\ge2$ should do the trick, I think.

Comment: For the latter, expand $\zeta(x)$ into its well-known infinite series, and then reverse the order of the two summations.

Comment: Lucian for the last sum it is quite clear  the main aim is to generalize the sums of the type.$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \zeta (k)}{k^n}$$